Blurry image of moon while it seems very sharp in the LCD
I am using a Nikon P1000 to take photos of the moon. I turn off the stabilizer and use a tripod. I try to get a sharp zoom on the moon by using manual zoom. I get very sharp images on the LCD of the machine. I take the photos by setting the shutter timer on 10S. Just after shooting, the images get blurry! I tried an enormous complex of adjustments; the problem is not solved! I use f8.0, a shutter speed of 400-1000, and iso 100-800. Any comments are appreciated to assist me in taking a sharp image as I see in the LCD of my camera.

This question is similar to: How can I achieve more clarity in my photos of the moon?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Before you take the photo, the LCD is showing you a video feed, not a "still image". The frame rate of the LCD display will affect the exposure time per frame. The LCD is also a much downsized resolution from your camera sensor's resolution. LCDs on the back of cameras lie like politicians!

Can you show an extract of one of your shots (near the moon's border)?

I have the P1000.  It is a very heavy camera and the tripod mount is on the bottom of the body.  When the lens is zoomed to long focal lengths the weight of the lens is very far forward of the tripod mount.  It would take a lot of resistance in the tripod head to keep the camera from rotating on the tripod.  You could improve this by making a plate that attaches to the camera at one end and the tripod at the other, shifting the center of gravity of the camera closer to the tripod head.  This is why interchangeable telephoto lenses come with tripod collars, but the design of the P1000 prevents that.
The P1000 has a mode for taking moon photos.  I don't know what it does, but I would assume it sets the lens to focus at infinity.  You could try using the regular automatic mode to see if what the camera thinks is infinity is not correct.  Is the moon overexposed from being too bright?  Try underexposing by 2 stops and see if it gets sharper.  You will lose shadow detail, but that is not the point of this.
As you didn't post a photo I don't know how blurry you mean.  The lens is not the sharpest, particularly at 3000 mm effective.  I use it handheld for birds all the time and the pictures look sharp at small sizes but you wouldn't blow them up too much.

Based on the information given, I think there is one possible cause that is not addressed in the other answers/links... your tripod is inadequate for the task.
This is a very common issue, especially at the lower end of the market. And IMO, people have very different opinions about what "solid"/"stable" actually means when it comes to a tripod. Unfortunately, I don't think you can really rely on the average review/opinion/recommendation about tripods without a lot of additional information/context.
To see just how stable your tripod actually is, set the camera to the longest focal length possible and zoom into the image on the LCD to 100%. Then tap the camera/tripod/etc... you are now looking at a 1:1 representation of the image movement on the sensor with a given vibrational input. This is a rather depressing test; there is pretty much no tripod/head that will not show a notable amount of image movement at long focal lengths/high magnification... and 3000mm effective is extremely demanding.
Outdoors a slight wind can be enough to cause motion blur with some tripods. And if the tripod is on a man made surface (floor/deck/patio/etc) simply moving in the proximity of the tripod can cause motion blur. Tripod resonance tends to be at a high frequency, which means that shutter speeds that are otherwise adequate may not be sufficient... i.e. your shutter speeds are adequate for the subject movement, but maybe not for tripod movement.
A quick look at the specs of your camera indicates that it has a silent shutter mode... you should enable that if not already. This will eliminate the shutter movement at the end of the 10 seconds and beginning of the image; which otherwise can cause vibration/motion blur. Also, a 10 second delay may not be long enough for the camera to completely settle; you might want to also use a remote release.

I actually had a tripod issue last month when taking pics of the moon with my Sigma 150-600. I have a decent Manfrotto tripod and pan-tilt head.  I ended up with lots of blurred images.  I've since invested in a bean bag support.

@PeterM,  a support like a beanbag is about as stable as possible...

To follow up, last week I used the bean bag (sitting it on my car) at the same location, and the images were very stable.

I think the issue here is the resolution of the LCD.
Nikon P1000 has 16 megapixels. That's more than any typical computer monitor for example. 4K resolution is far less than 16 megapixels, and most computers don't have 4K displays.
And the feeble LCD on the back of the camera has even less pixels. Your P1000 has 921000 dots. That roughly corresponds to 0.9 megapixels, since a dot is of single color, and 16 megapixel camera doesn't have 16 red megapixels, 16 green megapixels and 16 blue megapixels but rather 16 single-color megapixels with a Bayer filter.
So your images have 17 times more pixels than the LCD does. Therefore, a sharp image on the LCD doesn't end up being a sharp image when viewing the image file afterwards on a computer and zooming in.
Besides, the moon is of a single color, so the 16 megapixels can be argued to be equivalent to 16 million full RGB pixels, since the demosaicing algorithms take luminance information from every pixel. Chroma on JPG files is subsampled anyway. Therefore, it could be argued the image has more than 50 times the amount of pixels as the back LCD screen.

There are two main points:
How to take clear photos of the moon
There are some answers on taking better images of the moon already on the site.
See here:
How to capture details of the moon?
How can I achieve more clarity in my photos of the moon?
or externally:
https://photographylife.com/how-to-photograph-moon
Why does my image on the lcd look sharp, but mushy on pc?
If you are resampling an unsharp image to a smaller size, you are basically combining neighboring pixels. The way this is done will create a sharper image as high contrast edges will be enhanced. So the image on the screen always looks sharper.
This effect is used by videographers for producing higher image quality by filming a scene in say 4k and then rerendering the film to HD. This will also resample the image, evening out noise and sharpen contrast edges.
You can also test that at home by taking the unsharp image you took and save it at the resolution of your camera's LCD screen. The downsampled image will appear to be sharper.
Also you lcd screen is not using a your set exposure time, it is sampling the image multiple times per seconds and then using aggressive tweaking of the brightness to produce a preview image. So the while the sharpness of the lens will be reflected in the lcd screen image, the effects of exposure time is not.

OP says the exposure  1/400th-1/1000th of a second. The 10s mentioned is the delay that is used to make sure the shake induced by pushing the shutter button has dampened.

Uh... I see. I misunderstood that. Thanks for pointing out.
